# How do I make the hovered element to be active

Tags: html, css, sass, styles, styling

How do I make the hovered element to stay. As you can see in the [codepen](https://codepen.io/khamran1/pen/MWmpRZj) if I hover over the "Service" it shows the content but when I try to click on the content it disappears.

*index.html*

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
}
.list .item {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.list .item:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.list .item.item-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.list .item.item-dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.list .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 120px;
  bottom: -20px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.list .dropdown-content:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-right: 14px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  margin-left: -8px;
  top: 45%;
  left: -5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">Home</div>
  <div class="item">About</div>
  <div class="item item-dropdown">Services
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="item">Home</div>
      <div class="item">About</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: I also see that sometimes its working and sometimes it doesn't when you hover over from the beak it works but when trying hover over outside beak it doesn't.

Comment: So what you are trying to achieve is when you hover over service, it should be active, and it should not hide even if you move your cursor to other places, except other items in the same menu, rihgt ?

Comment: no, it should work the same way as a normal dropdown works. Like when I hover over service it should show a list and list should stay as I hover over it. Currently it disappears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to wrap your menu items inside an element with margin-left.

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
}
.list .item {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.list .item:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.list .item.item-dropdown {
  position: relative;
}
.list .item.item-dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
.list .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: -20px;
}
.list .dd-menu{
  position:relative;
  margin-left:20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
.list .dd-menu:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 17px solid transparent;
  border-right: 14px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 17px solid transparent;
  margin-left: -8px;
  top: 45%;
  left: -5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">Home</div>
  <div class="item">About</div>
  <div class="item item-dropdown">Services
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <div class="dd-menu">
        <div class="item">Home</div>
        <div class="item">About</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Immediate `absolute` positioned child shouldn't have any margin before it to make hover possible.

Comment: thank you so much it worked well specially the margin-left thing

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this to your scss code

```
.dropdown-content:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

[Working example](https://codepen.io/theanonymouskoder/pen/RwVpzWR?editors=1100)